# youtube iframe api events not firing on IE

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

java script code :

```
     var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;

window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady=function() {
      player = new YT.Player('video', {

          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange

          }
        });




}

  function onPlayerReady(event) {

    alert("onPlayerReady");

  }
   function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

    alert("stateChanged");

  }
```

and for the iframe in the html I wrote this

```
<iframe id="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CHE_oNJAOaU?enablejsapi=1&autohide=1&autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&playerapiid=ytplayer" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

when I run this on google chrome or safari the code works just fine and I got the alert messages but when I try it on IE nothing happens (using IE11)
I hope you guys have the solution I have been searching for two days now.